# User content of Cell to created a link

Tags: google-sheets, url, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of UPS tracking numbers. I want to turn them to links to UPS tracking website. The link to find the status of an item is https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_GB&requester=QUIC&tracknum=TRACKING_NUMBER_GOES_HERE/trackdetails

Is there a Google sheet formula that lets you take the content of the cell and place it into a link to them make a link to the UPS website?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,"https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_GB&requester=QUIC&tracknum="&Σ&"/trackdetails")))
```

[image]